# Leave key/values from array based on the part of the value anybody?

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

I have an array, where each key value contains meta information of picture divided by comma.
For the meta information A,B,C:

- A represents the ID of the picture
- B the order of picture
- C the color

---

```
 Array ( 
    [0] => 657,1,1
    [1] => 658,2,1
    [2] => 659,3,1
    [3] => 875,15,3
    [4] => 869,9,2
    [5] => 872,12,2
    [6] => 959,13,2
)
```

I was asking already of how to find the unique values of C, but now I want to filter out and return an array only with certain color - C values for representing to visitors images with color 3 only f.e.

I want to achieve a result like that by looping trough the array

```
<div class="smallgal" id="color-1">
    <img src="657.jpg"> 
    <img src="658.jpg">
    <img src="659.jpg">
</div>

<div class="smallgal" id="color-3">
    <img src="869.jpg"> 
    <img src="872.jpg">
    <img src="959.jpg">
</div>

<div class="smallgal" id="color-2">
    <img src="875.jpg"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Check [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this way:

```
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) { // Change that 3 if there are more colors
        echo '<div class="smallgal" id="color-'.$i.'">';
        foreach($picture_data as $value){
            $data = explode(',', $value);
            if ($data[2] == $i) {
                echo '<img src="'.$data[0].'.jpg">';
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';
}
```

Assuming that your data arry is called `$picture_data`.
I didn't worry about format, eficiency nor order of elements.

Answer (score 0):

This would modify your array

```
foreach($elements as &$element){
  $colors = explode(',', $element);
  $element = $colors[count($colors)-1]; // it could be explicitly 2 perhaps
  }
```

and this would not:

```
$c = array();
foreach($elements as $key=>$element){
  $colors = explode(',', $element);
  $c[$key] = $colors[count($colors)-1]; // the same, consider using 2
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```
$result = array_filter($array, function($val){
  return array_pop(explode(',',$val)) == 3;
});
```

Comment: elclanrs - edited my post to show you the result I want to get from this arrays mysteria.